# ¿Como adaptar el height de un iframe con fancybox en Chrome?

Tags: jquery

Estoy programando una web y estoy utilizando *fancybox* (última versión) para que, cuando presiono una imagen, se abra un html. Para eso usé la opción iframe que trae fancybox. Ahora, mi problema es que en Mozilla Firefox el html se adapta perfecto tanto en ancho como en alto, en cambio, en Chrome se ajusta bien el ancho pero el alto se extiende más de lo que debería, quedando un html más extenso.

Dejo una imagen de cada navegador para que se entienda:

Mozilla Firefox (lo marcado en azul es el espacio que está bien):

[image: Mozilla]

Google Chrome (lo marcado en rojo es lo que está de más):

[image: Chrome]

**EDIT:**

Código del index:
[image: index]

HTML que se visualiza:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como es el html que cae dentro del iframe?

Comment: Es un html simple, dentro del body hay 4 divs que la único que hacen es un hover para cambiar la imagen al pasar el mouse y la franja amarilla de abajo es un footer

Comment: es mas descriptivo si se ve el código html y el css asociado. al incluir el código podes agregar librerías externas como el css y el js de fancy box : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fancybox

Comment: Edito el th y agrego print del código para que veas

Comment: para código es recomendable poner texto